# Calculate average amount of elements in data stream in the past X seconds

Tags: algorithm, stream, average, moving-average

I have a queue of events, in which every event is represented only by its timestamp, and an integer X, that represents the amount of time I wish to calculate the average for. Whenever the current time minus the time of a certain event exceeds X, that event is removed from the queue, and I am constantly adding new events into the queue. I wish to calculate at every moment the average amount of events in the queue in the past X seconds.

I figure this should be reasonably simple to do, but I'm having some trouble in doing this calculation on the fly instead of calculating the average once every X seconds. I've seen some algorithms for calculating the moving average of the values in a data stream, but I don't want to calculate the average value of the elements (as my events don't have a value). Instead, I want to calculate the average amount of elements in the stream. Any idea about how I could do this? Thank you.

Comment: `the average amount of events in the queue in the past X seconds` - wouldn't that be an exact figure rather than an average?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't phrase that very well. I'm trying to calculate an average like "events per minute", however this would be expressed in a larger timespan, like that of an hour, so that I can put these averages into a graph of how many events are happening every minute, calculated at, let's say, every second. Does this make more sense?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question -- every second, sample the length of the queue, update the average of all the samples taken so far and add this average to the graph.